# PHP denying use of short hand "<?"

Tags: php, installation, migration, php-ini, php-shorttags

I just installed php 5.3.0 and it won't run php scripts utilizing short open tags like <?, only <?PHP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880150/why-would-shorthand-php-opening-statements-not-be-working

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to update your php.ini file.

Set short_open_tag = 1

See the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: Well i'll be damned.  I've been programming PHP for the past 12 years, i've done websites for major clients like McDonalds... I can't believe I forgot about "short_open_tag"!!!!!!!!

Thanks Aberon!

Answer (score 6):

That's because it's simply a bad practice. I suggest re-converting all your scripts to use `<?php`. If you're lazy, you can use a find and replace, if you have access to powerful command lines like bash you can use sed to do this for you.

Comment: Short opening tags are great for templates (and for non-template code you should only have the one opening tag at the beginning)

Answer (score 4):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

you need to

```
ini_set("short_open_tag", 1)
```

or adjust your systems php.ini file.