# PHP won't output value in shorthand

Tags: php, html, input

I have a weird issue where I am trying to use PHP in shorthand to output a value saved in the session. (Basically, if you type in a username and email address when signing up, but you get the email address wrong, instead of it clearing the username field it should persist and then you only have to recorrect the incorrect details.)

This is what I have for the output:

```
value="<?=$usern_value;?>"
```

Which is in my input:

```
<input type="text" id="inputUser" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?=$usern_value;?>" />
```

But it outputs this instead:

[image]

This is where the value of `$usern_value` is created:

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_SESSION['status']['register']['username'])){
        $usern_value = $_SESSION['status']['register']['username'];
   } else {
        $usern_value = "";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like this

```
value="<?php echo $usern_value;?>"
```

Because may be shorthand  is not enabled in your php version.I so you need to enable the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) option in the configuration file `php.ini`.You can try one of the following

- set the directive `short_open_tag = On` in your php.ini (the recommended way);
- call `ini_set("short_open_tag", 1);` in your code;
- add the following line to your .htaccess file:

  `php_value short_open_tag 1`

It's not recommend you use short tags (<? ?>). You should use the full length tags (<?php ?>). The short syntax is deprecated, and if you want to make your application portable, it's possible that short open tags are not allowed on another server and hence your application will break.

Comment: Perfect thanks. The tutorial I was following suggested this so maybe it is just old.

Comment: No maybe about it, the tutorial IS old.

Answer (score 2):

```
short_open_tags
```

are not enabled by default in most recent versions of PHP.

Either edit your `php.ini` or try

```
ini_set('short_open_tag', true);
```

Generally, and because of the fact that it's not enabled on many servers, for compatibility reason, .... long sentence, simply don't use this kind of syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of php you are using you have to set `short_open_tag = 1` in php.ini to get `<?=` to work:

From https://www.php.net/ini.core:

> short_open_tag boolean
>
> ...
>
> Note:
>
> This directive also affected the shorthand <?= before PHP 5.4.0,
> which is identical to <? echo.
> Use of this shortcut required short_open_tag to be on.
> Since PHP 5.4.0, <?= is always available.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
value="<? echo $usern_value; ?>"
```

and make sure you have enabled php to use shorthand. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527719/php-denying-use-of-short-hand)

Answer (score 0):

Simply way change your code like this

```
<input type="text" id="inputUser" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php echo $usern_value; ?>" />
```